# PHP OO - how do I establish class relationships between X has many Y

Tags: php, class, relationship

So I have 2 classes:  Lets call them Person and Car

I need to access some attributes from my person object in my Car class before I can instantiate.

Do I simply say something to the order of:    `$car = new Car($person);`
 If yes, then how do I access those object attributes in my Car class? Would it be something like this:

```
class Car{

    function __construct($person)
    {  
        $this->person = $person;  
    }

}
```

If no, what would be a way to achieve this?

Comment: That's precisely how to do it. The name for that is "dependency injection", whereby you pass instantiated objects into the constructor rather than instantiate them inside the object that needs them. You assigned it to `$this->person` so you can use it internally like `$this->person->name`

Comment: You answered your won question it seems, though you did not really talk in your question about the "has many" aspect mentioned in your question title.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski which would break Person encapsulation

Comment: *x has **many** y*... `Person::getCars();` would return an `ArrayIterator` object containing all the Mercedes'. `$this->cars->first();`, `$danFromGermany->getCars()->first();`

Comment: @DanFromGermany Sorry I should have mentioned the idea being that a person can have many cars. and the car should be able to know params from the person.

Comment: @It.levon what does the car need the person to do exactly?

Comment: @nikola Car would need to know things like person's height, weight, and other params to adjust driver seat and things of this nature.

Comment: @It.levon rather than reading the Persons params like weight, height etc. pass the Seat object to the person and tell it to adjust it for him/her self. From within the car say `$this->person->adjustSeat($this->driverSeat);`. Now in the adjustSeat method you have access to person's height, weight and things like that to properly push those to the Seat object. At the end, Seat is adjusted to person's liking.

Comment: @nikola, would I still need to pass the person object to car to be able to do $this->person->adjustSeat($this->seat); ?

Comment: Yes. But whether you're going to do it in the constructor depends on your application. There are apps where it doesn't make sense for car objects to exist without person(s) inside it. For those pass them in the constructor of the car, either with array, iterator, whatever you prefer. If your car object doesn't always require passengers you can have an `enter(Person $passanger)` method which you can call many times and it could keep working until the car is full, then throw an exception for example. Many ways there are :)

Answer (score 1):

We have some confusion here. Real world OOP, consider and compare:

A **car** is **given to** or bought by a **person:**

```
$person->addCar($car);
```

A **person** **is entering** the **car** (to sit on the left front seat):

```
$car->addPerson($person, Car::SEAT_FRONT_LEFT);
```

Where `Car::SEAT_FRONT_LEFT` is a `public const` member of `Car`.

The relations are important to be kept semantically correct to be able to construct working objects.

--

To implement this, it might be helpful to lookup the meaning of (`Aware`-)`Interface`.

Example classes I'd probably define:

```
interface Person {
    public function getHeight();
    public function setHeight();
}

class CarOwner implements Person {
    protected $height;
    protected $cars = array();

    public function getHeight();
    public function setHeight();

    public function getCars();
};

class Driver implements Person  {
    protected $height;

    public function getHeight();
    public function setHeight();
};

class Car {
    protected $persons = array(); // @var array
    protected $readyToDrive = false;

    public const SEAT_FRONT_LEFT  = 1;
    public const SEAT_FRONT_RIGHT = 2;
    // ...

    public function addPerson(Person $person, $seat) {
        if ($person instanceof Driver) {
            $this->isReadyToDrive(true);
        }

         // I know this is stupid but you get the point:
        if ($this->getDriver()->getHeight() < 140 && $this->getSeat()->getPosition() > 40) {
            throw new Exception('please set the seat to fit your height!');
        }

        if (!in_array($person, $this->persons)) {
            $this->persons[$seat] = $person;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('person is already in the car!');
            // Person first needs to "leave" the car! like:
            // $car->removePerson($person)->addPerson($person, Car::SEAT_REAR_LEFT);
        }
    }


   public function getDriver() {
       if (isset($persons[self::SEAT_FRONT_LEFT]) && $persons[self::SEAT_FRONT_LEFT] instanceof Driver) {
           return persons[self::SEAT_FRONT_LEFT];
       }
       else { //... }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to see it from encapsulation side, we need to think about it. Is it ok, if a car knows a Person, which is inside? Maybe we need a Service/Controller which takes this params?

```
function processSomething(Person $person, Car $car) {}
```

But your example is not bad at all. It is depended on the usecase. Its the way it is done, if a car may know about his person.

If you can have multiple persons, you can have this constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $personList) {
    //Check for a person
    if (count($personList) < 1) {
        throw new Exception('No person given');
    }

    //Validate list
    foreach ($personList as $person) {
        if (!$person instanceof Person) {
            throw new Exception('This is not a person');
        }
    }

    //Keep persons
    $this->personList = $personList;
}
```

Also note, if we want to have multiple Objects in our class, we can make an ContainerObject:

```
class ContainerObject {
    public $person;
    public $moreInfo;
    public $manyMoreInfo;
}

class Person {
    public function sayHello() {};
}

class Car {
    private $containerObj;

    function __construct(ContainerObject $obj) {
        $this->containerObj= $obj;
    }

    function foo() {
        $this->containerObj->person->sayHello();
    }
}
```